# Can I have lodash omit return a specific type instead of a partial type?

Tags: typescript, lodash

In the code below

```
import omit from "lodash/fp/omit";

type EnhancerProps = {
  serializedSvg: string;
  svgSourceId: string;
  containerId: string;
};

const rest = omit(["serializedSvg", "containerId"])(props);
```

rest is typed as Partial. What can I do to have omit return something more specific, like `{svgSourceId: string}` instead.

Comment: Not sure that TS can infer exactly what you're excluding here. All it knows is that you start with some type `T` and you end up with (potentially) less properties for `T`. If it knew *which* ones, then it could have used the `Exclude` helper but you can pass any array to `omit`. You might be able to do something with a wrapper function if the keys you'd omit are always the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Weird that `omit` doesn't infer types on its own. I'm not sure if there's a reason for that, but I was able to come up with a helper function that should do the trick.

```
function omitWithTypes<A extends ReadonlyArray<keyof B>, B extends Object>(
  typeArray: A,
  obj: B
) {
  return omit(typeArray)(obj) as Omit<B, A[number]>;
}
```

The [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk) utility type will allow you to narrow properties of a type. However if you want to convert the values of an array to a union type and pass to `Omit`, the array *must* be read only, which you can satisfy with the `as const` [assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to tell the TS compiler that it won't mutate.

```
const filter = ["serializedSvg", "svgSourceId"] as const;
const exclusive = omitWithTypes(filter, props);
```

OR

```
const exclusive = omitWithTypes(["serializedSvg", "svgSourceId"] as const, props);
```

You will get correct inferred types (though it is a little verbose since it's using the `Pick` utility type behind the scenes):

[image]

You will even get an error if you try to exclude values that aren't properties of the object being picked from:

[image]

Comment: "*Weird that `omit` doesn't infer types on its own*" let me give you two reasons: 1. "*the array must be read only*" 2. "*You will even get an error if you try to exclude values that aren't properties of the object being picked from*". Both of these would make `omit` harder to use for general purposes.